# Grep - find a file in current directory containing all *.py files

Tags: linux

I need to search for a string "django" in the current directory including only *.py files.

```
$grep -ir django *
```

lists all files, I need only *.py files...

Answer (score 1):

Use the find command:

```
find . -name "*.py" -exec grep django {} \;
```

If you are on a mac, add -H to show the line number.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$grep -ir django *.py
```